# Count from 1 to 24 and then restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a counter that counts from 0 to 24 and when it hits 24:

```
setInterval(function(){DayAndNight()}, 1000);

    var iState = 12;

    function DayAndNight()
    {
        //console.log('test');
        switch(iState)
        {

            case 1:
            { 
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "1";  
                iState++;
                break;  
            }

            case 2:
            {
                 document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "2";   
                 iState++;
                 break;    
            }     

            case 3:
            {
                 document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "3";
                iState++;
                break;
            }
```

and so on untill it hits 24 where I return to iState1:

```
            case 24:
            {
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "24";
                iState = 1;                                 
                break;                     
            }
```

This works well, and I can set it to start at iState 12, so it doesn't just count from 0 to 24.

However, I was wondering if there was an easier way of doing this task? This is a lot of code for a simple function. I've experimenting with something like this:

```
var time = setInterval(function(){TimeNumber();},1000);

function TimeNumber()
{
  for (var i=0;i<23;i++)
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = ???;  
}
```

But I don't know what the next step is.

I hope that you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: `var time = setInterval(TimeNumber, 1000);` is much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, remove your switch statement and use `innerHTML = iState` rather than the number, then use an if statement to reset to 0 if it's 24. having 24 switch cases that do the same thing is a little redundant.

Comment: Just use the modulo (%) operator. Keep incrementing the counter, but display (counter % 24).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
var time = setInterval(function(){TimeNumber();},1000);
var iState = 1;

function TimeNumber()
{
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = iState;
  iState++;

  if (iState === 25) {
    iState = 1;
  } 
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nXbUD/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#time').text(function(_,txt) {
        var n = parseInt(txt,10);
        return n>=24?0:n+1;
    });
},1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nTfe6/1/)

or whithout jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('time'),
        n  = parseInt(el.innerHTML,10);

    el.innerHTML = (n>=24?0:n+1);
},300);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var time = setInterval(TimeNumber, 1000);
var iState = 1;

function TimeNumber() {
    iState++;

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = iState;
    if (iState == 24) iState = 0;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e4qqn/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
function TimeNumber()
{
  if (iState == 24){
     iState = 0;
  }
  iState++;
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = iState.toString();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative

HTML

```
<div id="time"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var dayAndNight = (function () {
        var iState = 1,
            timeDiv = document.getElementById("time"),
            countNode;

        return function () {
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(iState);

            if (!countNode) {
                countNode = timeDiv.appendChild(textNode);
            } else {
                timeDiv.replaceChild(textNode, countNode);
                countNode = textNode;
            }

            iState += 1;
            if (iState > 24) {
                iState = 1;
            }
        };
    }()),
    intervalId = setInterval(dayAndNight, 1000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/uawxr/)

This solution  has some advantages in the fact that `iState` is now contained within a closure and can't accidentally be modified later in the script. (the accepted answer uses a local global, which could be changed later and if set greater than 25 then the count would never get reset because of the `===` check)

This solution also does not destroy the content of the element named `time` (the accepted answer uses `innerHTML`), and only updates it's own node. So you can happily add or remove content from the `time` element.

This solution also caches the element with the id of `time` so it is not looked up in the DOM each time an update occurs.

`innerHTML` will also not work when updating tables (IE and konquerer), this solution will. (you haven't specified what your element is but I guess it's not a table as you originally use `innerHTML`)

Any answers that do not store the `setInterval` id can not be stopped later in your script with `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

All these answers, and no modulus division.  Here's my 2 cents.

```
var time = setInterval(TimeNumber, 1000);
var iState = 1;

function TimeNumber() {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = iState;
    iState = (iState % 24) + 1;
}
```

Comment: OP has actually changed the spec to 1 to 24